# how can i listen to the bool variable and make an action

Tags: flutter, dart, addeventlistener

i have `StatefulWidget` and `local bool test = false` so for example i need to make an action if its value has been changed to true ,,

```
class FollowingList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String uid ;
  const FollowingList({Key? key,required this.uid}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FollowingListState createState() => _FollowingListState();
}


class _FollowingListState extends State<FollowingList> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if(// here i need to tell dart wait till test is == true and if it is so .. make an action  ){
    //i need to make an action or call a function ,,
}
  }

bool test = false`

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return // of course i can use here onPressed then setstate test = true then make an action This does not fit my case 
   but i need auto detect  
     
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use ValueNotifier :
https://medium.com/@avnishnishad/flutter-communication-between-widgets-using-valuenotifier-and-valuelistenablebuilder-b51ef627a58b
...
Or Property Change Notifier :
https://medium.com/flutter-nyc/introducing-property-change-notifier-10e6d27080a3

Comment: Are you using `test` as global variable ?

Comment: if you read the question you will know it is local , also no matter as mush as i need a way

Answer (score 0):

Use ValueNotifier. [Learn how to use](https://medium.com/@avnishnishad/flutter-communication-between-widgets-using-valuenotifier-and-valuelistenablebuilder-b51ef627a58b)

Step 1: Declare variable

```
ValueNotifier<int> buttonClickedTimes =ValueNotifier(0);
```

Step 2:Wrap it with builder

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: buttonClickedTimes,
  builder: (BuildContext context, int counterValue,Widget child){
  ///This trigger every time the value of 'buttonClickedTimes' changes
  return Text("Counter:$counterValue");
      }
)
```

Step 3:Try to change value

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap:()=>buttonClickedTimes.value= buttonClickedTimes.value+1,
  child: Text("Button",style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.button)
);
```

Comment: thanks but i already know  that , this is not fit my case

Comment: @Nadia Yaseen Can you describe what is missing here?

Comment: @NadiaYaseen if you just need to listen to the changes of the variable and not rebuild then you can try [this method](https://dartpad.dev/?id=5b2bdd4d8dfcd9efa14b5b415faf34f5)

Answer (score 0):

You could use ternary operations.
So after waiting till test is true, set state. And then your code could be something like :

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
if(// here i need to tell dart wait till test is == true and if it is so .. make an action  ){
 setState((){test = true;});
//i need to make an action or call a function ,,
}
}
```

Then :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return test == true ? YourWidget() : OtherWidget(); 
 
}
}
```

Comment: it is always true ,!!

Comment: So write a function to set it to false when you need it to be false and to true when you need it to be true. Or I'm not getting you well.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable like this:

`ValueNotifier<bool> test = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);`

Declare the function you want to execute when `test` changes:

```
void myFunc() {
    if ( test.value ) {
       // do your stuff
    }
}
```

In your initState() function:

`test.addListener( myFunc );`

Set change the value of test:

`test.value = true;`

Your function will be called.